# Node.js - Not loading referenced javascript and stylesheets on (ejs) files

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, ejs

I am new to NodeJs and WebStorm. I have created a new *"Node.Js Express App"* using ***ejs*** template. I have created a `Scripts` folder inside my app root directory and trying load those files on my `index.ejs` file inside `views` folder.

When I run page in Chrome, it gives the following 404 error. For example, in my `index.ejs` body tag file, if I say:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It will give following error:

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

I works fine in public folder by why it doesn't work if scripts and files are outside the public folder?

Comment: can you share your server config fig. the file in which express server is configured ?

Comment: Can you share your server.js??

Comment: What is the exact URL for such resource? What WebStorm version do use use exactly?